# Where is the documentation for HttpClient 4.1.x?

Tags: java, apache, httpclient, document, apache-httpclient-4.x

Where is the documentation for `HttpClient 4.1.x`?

I just want something like http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/index.html(`4.4.x`'s documentation)

---

## My sad story

I'm going to use `HttpClient 4.1.x`, and can't upgrade to `4.3.x` or `4.4.x` because the parent module (which calls my module) uses `4.1.x`. This is a typical problem in large companies.

First things first, I wanted to find the documentation for `HttpClient 4.1.x`, so I opened the home page of `HttppClient`:

http://hc.apache.org/

[image: http://hc.apache.org/]

But in the navigation I can only find documentation for `4.3` and `4.4`. I looked for something like `Older Versions` or `Version List`, but I couldn't find anything.

Then I tried searching (Google) and found the `4.2.x` homepage. I hoped this might link to `4.1.x` documentation, but no luck.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/index.html

[image: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/index.html]

I'm good at learning patterns, so I guess `4.1.x`'s homepage is:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.1.x/index.html

But, again, disappointment:

[image: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.1.x/index.html]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fortunately, the Wayback Machine can get you the archived site:
https://web.archive.org/web/20120103180744/http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html

The (pretty clumsy) alternative would be to build it yourself:

1. Check out HttpClient: `svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/tags/4.1.3 httpclient`
2. Build HttpClient's site, skipping subprojects: `mvn -pl . site` (the subprojects contain missing dependencies)
3. The build will still fail, but it will get far enough to generate HTML and PDF documentation in `target/site`, including a big tutorial PDF.

That worked for me, although it's a pretty clumsy process.